# Clonned Laravel/vue project from GIT and facing the error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i recently cloned a project from Git, and to install npm packages

i ran 2 commands after deleting package.lock file,

```
npm cache clean --force
```

```
npm install
```

and i also getting no error upon installing these packages

but when i run the project i am getting below error

https://www.screencast.com/t/RuN6CpF7alq

please click above link to see the error

I somehow no idea why is it happening, need your valueable suggestions.

Comment: does an 'npm run dev' move you forward at all?

Comment: yeah, it was generating no errors, anyways i had a NPM and NODE version compatibility issue with my project, resolved it, thanks alot :)